# Any different styles to show simple text for reading in an android activity?

Tags: textview, android

Can anyone tell me to show simple text to users to show in different styles to make it more attractive and efficient to read. Like glowing text or text in bubble like the same way message appears anything you can suggest please do help to me.
  I am making simple application to show almost 1-2 page text to user but i want to make it to look more attractive i have tried just by changing color of background and text but it sucks.
  Please tell me to anyway to show the text in different styles. That will help me a lot. Thanks in advance, Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the text its font. Fonts are Typfaces in Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

You could also add custom fonts to your application.
Tutorial:
http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-font-example

Comment: Thanks :D..+1 dude, i don't have reputation to vote up. Hope you will be satisfied with this comment

Answer (score 1):

As answered before, `Typeface` is a really good thing.
Secondly what kind of userbase are you supporting? Try adding settings for increasing font size change etc. And according to different people ( visually impaired etc) you can add different fonts.
Also for better experience, add swipe gestures, or actions on long click, and other gestures. To Use this click on [this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/): 
These things might also improve user experience.